# Refrescar DataTables en Fetch API Vanilla Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, datatables, fetch

tengo un problema. Estoy intentando actualizar o refrescar mi **Datatable** pero me dice el siguiente error: **Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3** ya que entiendo que no puedo iniciar Datatables dos veces pero como estoy haciendo el proyecto en **Vanilla Js con Fetch API**, ya que no quiero utilizar mucho el **jQuery** en pleno *2021* pero no logro que se refresque la tabla luego de una modificación de datos. Solo veo los datos actualizados en **Datatable** luego de un **F5**.

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    Tabla();
});

Tabla = () => {
fetch('data.php').then((res) => res.json())
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      let html = '';
      for (let i in response) {
        html += `<tr>
          <td>${response[i].dni}</td>
          <td>${response[i].cedula}</td>
          <td>${response[i].nombre}</td>
          <td>${response[i].apellido}</td>
          <td>${response[i].posicion}</td>
          <td>
                        <a href="#" class="" data-id="${response[i].id}" onclick="Mostrar(${response[i].id})">
                            <i class="large material-icons">visibility</i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="" href="#" onclick="Editar(${response[i].id})">
                            Editar
                        </a>
                        <a class="" onclick="Eliminar(${response[i].id})">
                            Eliminar
                        </a>
                    </td>
        </tr>`;
      }
      document.querySelector('.tbody').innerHTML = html;  
      $('#tablita').DataTable({
        autoWidth: false,
        order: [[ 0, 'desc' ]]
      });
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
}


// Modificar
Formulario.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch('registrar.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body:datos
  }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
     Respuesta.innerHTML = `
       ${data.estudiante}
      `;
    if (data.editar == true) {
      Formulario.reset();
      $('#tablita').DataTable().data.reload();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Además en la consola, me dice un error: $(...).DataTable(...).data.reload is not a function, Como hago para que se refresque mi Datatables sin actualizar la página?

Comment: He intentado con $('#tablita').DataTable().destroy(); funciona pero no es "reactiva", ya que destruye la tabla y luego la vuelve a rellenar por 2 segundos aprox.

Comment: Hay una pequeña inconsistencia entre _"ya que no quiero utilizar mucho el jQuery "_ y el uso de `DataTable`, que es una extensión de jQuery, con el que se maneja muy fácilmente. Aquí el problema principal es que `DataTable` puede crear y redibujar la tabla a partir de un arreglo (o peticiones AJAX) y, en tu afán de hacerlo con Javascript puro, complicas todo al remplazar directamente el contenido HTML de la tabla. Mi sugerencia: Lee nuevamente los tutoriales de DataTable, especialmente [el dedicado a AJAX](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html).